# preg_replace cannot perform simple math in the replacement

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I've tried all kinds of different sequences and escaping, but no luck. Preg_replace is ignoring the `$i` and using the integer after the `+` as its' replacement.

**First Example:**

```
$i = 1;
$s = preg_replace( '/\[$/', '${' . $i + 1 . ':[', $s );
var_dump( $s );
```

Result: `${1:[ // should be 2`

**Second Example:**

```
$i = 1;
$s = preg_replace( '/\[$/', '${' . $i + 9 . ':[', $s );
var_dump( $s );
```

Result: `${9:[ // should be 10`

**Without addition it works fine:**

```
$i = 12;
$s = preg_replace( '/\[$/', '${' . $i . ':[', $s );
var_dump( $s );
```

Result: `${12:[ // okay`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need parenthesis to group the expression so that the addition happens before the concatenation.

```
$s = preg_replace( '/\[$/', '${' . ($i + 1) . ':[', $s );
```

Comment: Oh for the love of... Is that a requirement of the preg_'s or is it discussed elsewhere in the php.net docs?

Comment: That's the [operator precedence](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) at work, it'll happen with any string.